# Dijkstra's - Queue

Tags: c++, queue, dijkstra

I use following code for the Dijkstra's algoritm:

```
int Graph::ShortestPath(Vertex *start, Vertex *end)
{
    int posStart = IndexOfNode(start);
    int posEnd = IndexOfNode(end);
    int result;

    bool visit[cntNodes];
    int distance[cntNodes];
    // Initialization: set every distance to -1 until we discover a path
    for (int i = 0; i < cntNodes; i++) {
        visit[i] = false;
        distance[i] = -1;
    } // for

    // The distance from the source to the source is defined to be zero
    distance[posStart] = 0;

    Queue *q = new Queue(maxNodes);
    q->Enqueue(posStart);
    while (!q->Empty()) {
        int next, alternative;
        q.Dequeue(next);
        for (int i = 0; i < cntNodes; i++) {
            if (adjmatrix[next][i]) {
                alternative = distance[next] + adjmatrix[next][i];
                if (visit[i]) {
                    if (alternative < distance[i]) {
                        distance[i] = alternative;
                        q.Enqueue(i);
                    } // if
                }// if
                else {
                    distance[i] = alternative;
                    visit[i] = true;
                    q.Enqueue(i);
                } // else
            } // if
        } // for
    }
    delete q;
    result = distance[posEnd];
    delete[] visit;
    delete[] distance;
    return result;
}
```

Right now I use an own created class called Queue:

```
Queue *q = new Queue(maxNodes)
```

Is there any C++ standard Queue which I could use instead of my own implementation.

I only need this functionality:

```
Queue *q = new Queue(maxNodes);
q->Enqueue(posStart);
    q.Dequeue(next);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Please check the Standard Template Library for this and numerous other collection classes.

Here's a link:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/

Comment: STL term is incorrect in this context. What you are talking about is C++ Standard Library. Do not confuse STL with a standard library — these two are very different. Only recruiters who don't know anything about it may put it into a job qualification requirements :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, now I use:

   queue<int> q;
   q.push(posStart);
   next = q.front();
   q.pop();
   q.push(i);

Answer (score 3):

A [priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is a good fit for Dijkstra's algorithm, and decreases the runtime complexity of the algorithm (compared to a normal queue)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three things that come to mind:

1. [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) — a double-ended queue.
2. [std::queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) - a queue container adapter.
3. [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) — priority queue.

There are also other containers and algorithms that can be found in C++ Standard Library.